# Should I install the Debian or xUbuntu version of TeXstudio on 12.04?

Tags: software-installation, latex, text-editor

I'd like to install the newest 64-bit version of TeXstudio on Ubuntu 12.04. Since it's not in one of the default repositories, I need to get it a different way. The [TeXstudio homepage](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/index.html#download) has links for Debian 6.0 and 7.0, as well as links for xUbuntu 12.04. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118621/46459) suggests downloading the xUbuntu version but doesn't compare it to any other versions or explain why.

Which one should I choose, and why? Or is this something that I should ask the developers of the program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *xUbuntu* :
>   The 'x' stands for *whatever version*. So, in this case, "xUbuntu" means "Ubuntu or Xubuntu or Kubuntu or Lubuntu".
>
> *Which one should I choose ?* : In my opinion, the best would be to take the xUbuntu way, because it's more likely to have the needed dependencies for Ubuntu.
>
> *Should I ask the developers ?* : I don't think it's necessary, for the reasons already given.

---

So, to install the 2.5.2 version of TeXstudio on Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64 (64bits), you should do this :

```
wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/jsundermeyer/xUbuntu_12.04/amd64/texstudio_2.5.2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i texstudio_2.5.2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Or, graphically, download [this package](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/jsundermeyer/xUbuntu_12.04/amd64/texstudio_2.5.2_amd64.deb) and install it with the Software Center.

Comment: Oh, I thought "xUbuntu" was referring to Xubuntu! Since, as stated in the question, I want the newest version (2.7.0 at the time of this comment),  I'll download it from the project homepage I linked in the question.

Answer (score 4):

There also is a well maintained ppa for installing the most recent version of TeXstudio (currently 2.6.6.):

```
ppa:blahota/texstudio
```

This gives you the advantage to install through your default package management, and to get regular updates. Please read more on PPAs here:

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I see that István Blahota is one of the TeXstudio contributors, so the ppa can probably be trusted. Hopefully they'll soon have an update to the newest version (2.7.0) that launched 7 days ago.